# How to link app (docker container) running on one host to db (container) running on different host?

Tags: docker, jenkins

How to create an environment where an app (container) runs on one jenkins agent & the db (container) running on another agent?

Answer (score 0):

map the ports on the hosts for both containers and use the host ips/names to connect as you would do without the containers.

If you plan to do everything from docker, you might want to give a check to docker swarm.